# Simplify the following, Indicies

Tags: linear-algebra

Hello can someone please help me simplify the following:

$$j^6 \times j^{3.2}\times  j^{-3} \times j^{-4}$$

Thank you,

Rob

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary? or just a variable?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I have edited your question to typset the Maths properly - take a look and check I haven't made a mistake. Also, it is usual on this site to provide your thoughts on this question and explain where you are stuck. What laws about exponents do you know? And I echo @MysteryGuy - is $j=\sqrt{-1}$ or not?

Comment: Hint. One may recall that $a^r\times a^s=a^{r+s}$

Comment: I'm not to sure if they are imaginary or variable. I am only just learning about this, So trying to work out hoe to simplify it.

Comment: Since $j^{3.2}$ would be ambiguous if $j^2=-1$, so it is probably just a variable. @Rob_Brown Is this from an algebra/pre-calculus class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint -

When terms with same base are in multiply then powers of the terms are added.

So add all powers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What about the minus, Do I just minus that of the total? Or write it separate?

Comment: It becomes $$j^{6+3.2-3-4}$$

Comment: Oh right, I though you added, subtracted them, then had just one number. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Mine pleasure to help you.